# How are the different batches from training data being obtained in Tensorflow rnn tutorial code?

Tags: tensorflow

In the Tensorflow tutorial code for RNN how is the next batch obtained? In reader.py the function ptb_producer produces one batch of dimension [batch_size x num_steps] at a time through a dequeue method But it is not called multiple times in ptb_word_lm.py to get all the batches. Any help in understanding how different batches are being obtained will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, Welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

Have you noticed that these code at ptb_word_lm.py(line 376)  as below:

```
sv = tf.train.Supervisor(logdir=FLAGS.save_path)
    with sv.managed_session() as session:
      for i in range(config.max_max_epoch):#LOOK!The param max_max_epoch.
        lr_decay = config.lr_decay ** max(i + 1 - config.max_epoch, 0.0)
        m.assign_lr(session, config.learning_rate * lr_decay)
```

This is a loop obviously,and the op `m.assign_lr()`was executed `max_max_epoch` times.what's more, `m = PTBModel(is_training=True, config=config, input_=train_input)`,(ptb_producer produces one batch when `sess.run()` was called once), right? So, actually, function ptb_producer was called multiple times in ptb_word_lm.py. p.s. I'm not sure if it's correct.Hope helps.